# Play animation once, stop, later play reverse

Tags: three.js

I want to play an animation once, stop at the final frame and then return a function which I can later call to play the animation once reverse to get to the starting position. What I have:

```
 function animate() {
    ...
    gltf.animations.forEach((animation) => {
      const action = object.animation.clipAction(animation).setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat, 1);
      action.clampWhenFinished = true;
      action.play();
    });

    return () => {
      gltf.animations.forEach((animation) => {
        const action = object.animation.existingAction(animation);
        action.timeScale = -1;
        action.play();
      });
    }
 }
```

`object.animation` is the AnimationMixer for the object. The first part is working, but when I call the returned function nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation states that `clampWhenFinished` is setting `.paused=true` ([clampWhenFinished](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=animation#api/en/animation/AnimationAction.clampWhenFinished)). You need to therefore set it to `false` when you want to resume the animation instead of triggering `.play()` again.
Furthermore you should reset the animation to be able to repeat it and you should set the looping to `LoopOnce` to play the `AnimationAction` only once. If you change your code like this it should work:

```
function animate() {
    ...
    gltf.animations.forEach((animation) => {
      const action = object.animation.clipAction(animation);
      action.reset();
      action.clampWhenFinished = true;
      action.timeScale = 1;
      action.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce, 1);
      action.play();
    });

    return () => {
      gltf.animations.forEach((animation) => {
        const action = object.animation.existingAction(animation);
        action.timeScale = -1;
        action.paused = false;
      });
    }
 }
```